# Syntax to apply two functions on one string

Tags: php

Why was this closed?  People really think that nobody else will ever need to learn how to apply two functions to one string?  That is what the question was BTW.

*****This question has been solved 
working code:

```
link_up(htmlentities($row['note']))
```

Thanks for the help, just needed the correct syntax I guess.  Thanks!

Ok so I have a form that visitors can fill out to leave a note.  I created a function called link_up that turns a typed web address in the note into a clickable link without using html tags.  The problem is since I will be displaying user input I would also like to use htmlentities when it is displayed.  This is my code that works without htmlentities.

This works but isn't secure...

```
<tr><td class='note'>" . link_up($row['note']) . "</td>" ;
```

this also works but doesn't use the link_up function I created for it

```
echo "<tr><td class='note'>" . htmlentities($row['note']) . "</td>" ;
```

so what I need is something like this (but this obviously doesn't work)

```
echo "<tr><td class='note'>" . htmlentities . link_up($row['note']) . "</td>" ;
```

So I guess what I am asking is, how can I use both the htmlentities function AND the link_up function I made at the same time so that when $row['note'] is echo'd it both is secure and works as intended?   Or maybe it makes more sense to ask how can I use two functions on one echo string at the same time?

This is the link_up function

```
function link_up($text)  
{  
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$3\" class=\"notelink\" target=\"blank\">$3</a>", $text);  
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" class=\"notelink\" target=\"blank\" >$3</a>", $text);  
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\">$2@$3</a>", $text);  
return($text);  
}
```

Comment: eh would it work like this? `htmlentities(link_up($row['note']))`

Comment: `htmlentities(link_up($row['note']))` or add htmlentities to the function

Comment: htmlentities(link_up($row['note']))  works without error but breaks the link_up function   would it help if I added the link_up function code?

Comment: It does'nt break the function, but the function should return the resulting HTML to be entity encoded.

Comment: then add it inside the function to the link string, not the href

Comment: @ButterDog: It does not break the function, it re-encodes the string. That is by intention. Don't encode if you don't want to encode.

Comment: Thats what i mean by breaking it.  maybe if I reverse the order so it would be  link_up(htmlentities($row['note']))  ?

Comment: you should wrap $3\$3\$2@$3 in htmlentities not th erest of the string

Comment: reversing link_up and htmlentities did the trick.   working code   link_up(htmlentities($row['note']))

Comment: How about just using `serialize()` on the whole ting and be done with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very big misunderstanding (just saying so you get things ordered more easily).

The `htmlentities()` function is to encode text so that it appears unchanged inside a HTML document.

However in your case you already produce the HTML to be used in the document *as HTML* for the links, so that the links are in the hypertext:

```
link_up()
```

You might have mixed both that much that those two function do not work good hand-in-hand. However if you're lucky, they work very well hand-in-hand, just using them in the other order:

```
link_up(htmlentities($row['note']));
```

That is first in the inner to create the HTML and then add more HTML around links.

Comment: Thanks.  No misunderstanding, just needed the syntax to use two functions.  Never needed to use more than one at a time.  Thanks what you suggested does work.

Comment: Ah okay. I did fear you would have mixed that HTML is not TEXT is not HTML and you can do everything always.

Answer (score -2):

Try this? I have the done the same but I just created my link rather then using a function call.

```
 <tr><td class='note'><?php echo link_up(htmlentities($row['note']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td>"
```

Comment: The infamous stackoverflow insta-minus-one... Test if this works please OP?

Comment: Yea, that is the syntax i need but it makes my link_up function pointless.  reversing htmlentities and link_up works as I like though as it applies the link_up function first, then htmlentities.   This code works   link_up(htmlentities($row['note']))      Thanks for your help.  I really just needed the syntax I guess

Comment: Updated for correctness. hakre has a very good explanation of the your issue. Might I suggest explicitly stating which encoding and how you want the quotes to work? http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Love when people don't explain a vote down

Comment: Wasn't me.  I was gonna mark your answer as correct but then you pointed me to hakre instead,  personally I would give you an up vote but am still locked out from doing so without a >15 rep.   Thanks Rixhers

Comment: Don't worry about it, and yes hakre's answer explains more then my answer does, (silly me) however you should look into actually setting the encoding type and the constant type